# Autoincrement start at x

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

With Nodejs and TypeORM I want an incremental column, like this:

```
@Column()
@Generated('increment')
public orderNumber: number;
```

Is there a way I can make TypeORM to start counting at say 9000?

Comment: See [THIS](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2153). In summary you can't directly. What you can do is create a migration that set the starting value of the autoincrement primary key. There is no standard SQL so you have to search how to do it for your database.

Comment: PS: If *orderNumber* is a primary key and increment replace the decorators with only this: **@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()**

Comment: PS: If your order number must be unique and "safe" use uuid instead of simple number increment

Comment: orderNumber is not a primary key, so it doesn't need to be safe :)

Answer (score 1):

While creating your table in Database,Do something like

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.order_number_seq
START WITH 9000
INCREMENT BY 1
NO MINVALUE
MAXVALUE 2147483647
CACHE 1;

CREATE TABLE public."order" (
id uuid DEFAULT public.uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
number integer DEFAULT nextval('public.order_number_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
name character varying NOT NULL,
due_date date NOT NULL);
```

And then in your code you can use:

```
@Column()
@Generated('increment')
number?: number;
```

Here, i have used Postgresql.