# start ids at an arbitrary number in prisma data model

Tags: prisma, prisma2

Say one has a prisma data model specified like this

```
// schema.prisma
model Transaction {
id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
// other stuff...
}
```

What if one wanted to start the ids at some arbitrary number?

After looking at the prisma reference docs, I have not seen a hint on how do this.

Comment: From my research, it does not seem that prisma supports that althout apparently at least `postgresql` does : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62692832/autoincrement-start-at-x